# How do I prevent Django from interpreting a block which contains curly quotes?

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm working on a website which uses Django templates, and I have to produce HTML which contains paired curly quotes.  Is there any way to disable Django's tag processing for a block of code?  Something like a literal block tag would be nice, so that:

```
{% literal %}
 {% LITERAL {{ BRACES }}
{% endliteral %}
```

... would produce `{% LITERAL {{ BRACES }}` in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:
Your syntax is currently impossible with the current lexer / parser system.

Why?  Basically the template system has a Lexer and a Parser.  The Lexer takes the template string as input, and tokenizes it.  The parser then takes the list of tokens in its constructor and parses them into a list of a bunch of Nodes for the compiled template.  The template tags and filters only have access to the already constructed parser -- you can't access the initial lexer string.  See the comments in `django/templates/__init__.py`

However, there is a solution.  It's not mine (see below), but its to basically use server side includes {% ssi some_file.html %} to include an extra file that has the literal text.  Yes this is an ugly solution; but without a major rewrite of the templating system it will have to suffice.

[Easy Way to Escape Django Template Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184925/easy-way-to-escape-django-template-variables)

Answer (score 5):

For the record, this is possible now with the template tag verbatim.

Comment: Here's a link to the documentation for the `verbatim` tag:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#verbatim

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#templatetag

Comment: Useless.  You're seriously suggesting I should write the above as '{% templatetag openblock %} LITERAL {% templatetag openvariable %} BRACES {% templatetag closevariable %}'?  A block could conceivably contain hundreds of brace pairs.