# Django Template - Stop processing template

Tags: python, django

I am looking for way to clean up a template in django.  A simple solution would be to break this up into multiple templates, but we do not want to do that.

We basically have the following

```
{%if data.some_state %}
    Display some markup
{% else %}
   {%if data.some_state_2 %}
       State 2 different html view 
   {% else %}
        {%if data.process_data %}
           Display some list of data
        {% else %}
           No Data to display!
       {% endif %} <!-- if data.process_data-->
   {% endif %} <!-- if data.some_state_2 -->
{% endif %} <!-- if data.some_state -->
```

So that is extremely confusing and hard to read.  If I could do this in a "function" i would use if/else if or returns.

Is there a way in template language to do something like (stop_processing_template would tell the template we are done... ):

```
{%if data.some_state %}
    Display some markup
{% endif %}
{% django_stop_processing_template %}


{%if data.some_state_2 %}
       State 2 different view
{% endif %}
{% django_stop_processing_template %}

{%if data.process_data %}
           Display some list of data
{% endif %}
{% django_stop_processing_template %}

 No data provided !
```

Comment: good luck! I think that it's a good idea....

Comment: Good luck with that one...as the original Django creators stated, they removed some programming functionality so non-programmers - that is, designers - could continue to work. Best example is not including the elif tag.

Comment: @Edwin They just added the [`{% elif %}` tag](https://code.djangoproject.com/changeset/17187) :)

Comment: @Mandx Cool! I don't get Django through the trunk, though, so I still don't have it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [jinaj2](http://jinja.pocoo.org) for templating that view (or the whole project), it supports `if`/`elif`/`else` branching:

```
{% if data.some_state %}
    Display some markup
{% elif data.some_state_2 %}
    State 2 different view
{% elif data.process_data %}
    Display some list of data
{% endif %}
```

There are a couple different packages which it easy use jinja2 in a django project, I've used both [coffin](https://github.com/coffin/coffin) and [djinja](http://github.com/syrusakbary/djinja) for this.

Comment: He could also try one of the "elif" tags available at [djangosnippets](http://djangosnippets.org/search/?q=elif)

Comment: Nice, I didn't realize any had written a snippet to add `elif` tags.

Comment: The `{% elif %}` tag was [finally added](https://code.djangoproject.com/changeset/17187) to django.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure what your stop processing template logic would do; but a cleaner way to do your logic would be to write a custom tag that takes your arguments and then returns only the HTML relevant to your variables.  This way you remove the `if/else` loops and instead replace all that with a simple `{% do_stuff %}` tag.

*Edit*

This is a very simple implementation to give you some idea on how the logic would go.

First, you create templates for each variation and store them somewhere django can find them.

Then, a simple tag that renders the exact template you want (this is non tested, psuedo):

```
from django import template
from django.db.models import get_model
register = template.Library()

class ProcessData(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, var_name):
        self.obj = get_model(*var_name.split('.'))
    def render(self, context):
        if self.obj.some_state:
           t = template.loader.get_template('some_markup_template.html')
           result = 'something'
        else:
           if self.obj.some_state_2:
              t = template.loader.get_template('some_different_html_view.html')
              result = 'something'
       else:
          if self.obj.process_data:
             t = template.loader.get_template('some_list_data.html')
             result = 'something'
          else:
             t = template.loader.get_template('no_data.html')
             result = 'something'
        return t.render(Context({'result': result}, autoescape=context.autoescape))

@register.tag
def process_data(parser, token):
    try:
        tag_name, arg = token.contents.split(None, 1)
    except ValueError:
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError("%r tag requires arguments" % token.contents.split()[0])
    return ProcessData(arg)
```

Finally, in your template:

```
{% load my_tags %}
{% process_data data.mymodel %}
```

Comment: Think of a stop processing like a "return" for a method.  Once you hit the line I dont want you to process anything below...  If you have that you dont need to do an if else... you would just have a bunch of ifs...

Comment: Can you throw in some psuedo code to show what you are talking about.

Comment: Ignoring the fact that I dont want to have multiple templates, +1 because its a way to do it.  I didn't want to break it up into multiple templates because this is going to happen in  couple of other places, but maybe I need to rethink how we are doing it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Though I think [@burhan's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8449700/911557) approach is better, you could also do what you want to do by using a custom tag that sets a context variable to a boolean and than outermost else part could also be converted into a if tag

```
#Set a context variable nodata to True 
{% setnodata True %}  
{%if data.some_state %}
    Display some markup
    #Set context variable nodata to False  
    {% setnodata False %}
{% endif %}

{%if data.some_state_2 %}
    State 2 different view
    #Set context variable nodata to False  
    {% setnodata False %} 
{% endif %}

{%if data.process_data %}
    Display some list of data
    #Set context variable nodata to False  
    {% setnodata False %}
{% endif %}

{% if nodata %}
    No data provided !
{ % endif %}
```

The `setnodata` custom tag simply sets the context variable `nodata` to True or False depending upon the argument.

Answer (score 1):

today I meet the same question.
And I find this tag **{% verbatim %} {% endverbatim %}** .This works in Django1.5+
An example:

```
  {% verbatim %} 
  <div class="entry">
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <div class="body">
      {{ body }}
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endverbatim %}
```

You can also look below for more details:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/-_wBLDuzaNs
- [Handlebars.js in Django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229484/handlebars-js-in-django-templates)